# The power button turns MacBook off, but not back on

Tags: macbook-pro, power

I have:

- replaced/soldered a new keyboard connector on the logic board as it had a missing pin,
- replaced the keyboard twice (the second and third keyboards work correctly),
- tried jump starting the computer on with the jumpers but this did not work,
- performed many PRAM resets,
- repaired Disk and Permissions in Disk Utility,
- ran Apple Hardware Test in short and extended mode without any issues identified,
- attempted to do an SMC reset (although I don't see any sign of rather it happened or not).

---

Does anyone know why the power button would turn the computer off, but won't turn the computer on? This is even though removing the mag safe, removing the battery, and then reconnecting the mag safe power supply does turn the computer on automatically. Once on, the computer appears to work absolutely perfect.

Yosemite OS X 10.10 on mid 2010 MacBook Pro 15"

Comment: What makes you believe the power button is not broken?